# more pythonic version of list iteration function

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

Is there a more Pythonic way of defining this function?

```
def idsToElements(ids):
    elements = []
    for i in ids:
        elements.append(doc.GetElement(i))
    return elements
```

Maybe its possible with list comprehension. I am basically looking to take a list of ids and change them to a list of elements in something simpler than defining a function.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[`map()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) is a Python built-in which does exactly what you want.

```
def idsToElements(ids):
    return map(doc.GetElement, ids)
```

The use of `map()` vs the use of list-comprehensions is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247486/python-list-comprehension-vs-map).

The most popular (and accepted answer) conclusion is quoted here:

> map may be microscopically faster in some cases (when you're NOT making a lambda for the purpose, but using the same function in map and a listcomp). List comprehensions may be faster in other cases and most (not all) pythonistas consider them more direct and clearer.

Answer (score 29):

If a list comprehension is all that you wanted

```
def idsToElements(ids):
    return [doc.GetElement(i) for i in ids ]
```